# On a VMWare Windows host, I have no host<>VM connectivity, But can SSH from other nodes on the LAN, and VM has WAN connectivity

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ssh, vmware

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Install Bionic server VM on VMWare Workstation 15 running on Windows 10.
  VM is set with manually configured Bridge networking to host physical
  network adaptor, and also has a linux bridge configured inside the VM
  for container workloads. Verify VM has connectivity (sudo apt update
  or ping gateway).  VM has static IP configured on host LAN. (works)
- Attempt to SSH into or ping Bionic VM by IP from Windows host (fails)
- Attempt to ping VMWare host from VM (fails) Attempt to ping or SSH
  into VM from another Ubuntu machine on the same LAN (works)

The Windows host has Windows Firewall disabled, but I'm not ruling out some surprise firewall issue.  It also kind of sounds like MACVLAN behavior, but unless VMWare is quietly configuring this without my knowledge, I don't see this being the issue.  Any pointers to debugging this would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I never found the source of this issue, however I managed to resolve it by uninstalling VMWare, removing all virtual interfaces from device manager, and reinstalling after a reboot.